# Error using barcode scanner in iOS PhoneGap

Tags: iphone, cordova

I am working on barcode scanning App. I have download the sample code from GitHub. When I run that project I get an error. Please help me to solve it.

```
ERROR: Plugin 'NetworkStatus' not found, or is not a CDVPlugin. Check your plugin mapping in Cordova.plist.
2012-11-28 14:12:36.198 BarCodeScannerCDV[942:40b] FAILED pluginJSON = {"className":"NetworkStatus","methodName":"getConnectionInfo","arguments":["NetworkStatus0"]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: You are using this plugin- `https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner`

Comment: yes...but getting error.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to used updated phonegap framework (Cordova 2.2.0), because this was a [bug in Cordova 1.6.0.](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/incubator-callback-dev/201204.mbox/%3CCAK-b5ZxBdp=rpUXfKGvGBAG56RVhGTqWmUc6WBS19qN0eLOVCw@mail.gmail.com%3E)

Please see following comment by Shazron Abdullah in [Google Phonegap group](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/phonegap/bl2t_J0c4RI):

```
There is a new Cordova.plist because of the unified JS changes. Check
out the "Cordova Upgrade Guide" in your .dmg (Guides subfolder), or:
"Upgrading Cordova 1.5.0 projects to 1.6.0" step 8 of
https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md#upgrading-older-cordova-plugins-to-16x
```

The [BarcodeScanner](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner) plugin for iOS-Phonegap is stable one, please update your phonegap framework to 2.2.0.

In Phonegap 1.6.0 and below, network connection class name is `Network Status` but for Phonegap 1.6.1 and above, network connection class name is `CDVConnection`.